# ionic: Can I disable the swipe action in a certain area <div> in <ion-slide>?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Basically, I want to put a  inside . However, the ion-slide swipe is so sensitive, so I cannot scroll the content in . It just swipes to the next slide.

Is it possible to disable the swipe action in a certain area in ?

[image]

As shown in the picture, I want to disable the swipe action on the B area. I guess (if possible) I need to put some class in ion-scroll and/or div under it, but I could not figure it out.

This is my partial HTML code:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">    
  <ion-slide>
  ... // A area content
  <ion-scroll direction="x" ...>
    <div style="width: 5000px; height: 100px" ...>
      // B area. Very wide content
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
  ... // C area content
 </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Well i thing you can Find your solution on this link ->
http://codepen.io/kmartinezmedia/pen/agKbr

Comment: @Lakshya thanks for your link. However, I am puzzled. Do you mean it's not possible? The link title says, "Slide-box scrolling not working." I have no problem to put the y-axis scroll in <ion-slide>, but I cannot put the x-axis scroll. That's my question.

Comment: Then i have no idea about it

Comment: @Lakshya Thanks! It would be nice to have such UI. Let' me dig more. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another approach:
add these to the wide element:

```
<div on-touch="mouseoverWideDiv()" on-release="mouseleaveWideDiv()">
```

then in your controller:

```
$scope.mouseoverWideDiv = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
};

$scope.mouseleaveWideDiv = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(true);
};
```

Comment: wait, do you want to disable the slideboxes when scrolling in the 'B'-area or do you want to disable the scroll of the 'B'-area itself?

Comment: I want to disable the slideboxes when scrolling in the 'B'-area. Your solution works well. I was expecting there is a simple CSS to disable sliding, but your solution actually works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Here is another way of doing this:
In your controller add a function:**

```
$scope.disableSwipe = function() {
   $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
};
```

**In your view add the ng-init attribute on the slide-box element**

```
<ion-slide-box ng-init="disableSwipe()">
```

This will disable the slide-event. 
You can now use a controller function to slide to a given index like this:

Comment: Thanks. It's a good idea, though. Do you think I can just disable a certain area? BTW, It seems after the "index like this:" is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Since google sent me here when i was searching for solutions using ion-slides (instead of ion-slide-box) i will leave here the solution i ended up using.

One thing first: ion-slide-box is currently deprecated, so you should use ion-slides now.

First set options variable in ion-slides element:

```
<ion-slides options="options">
```

Then inside your controller you should configure the options variable with the noSwiping options as follows:

```
$scope.options = {
            noSwiping: true,
            noSwipingClass: 'do_not_swipe',
        }
```

And then, in an element inside your ion-slide-page add the "do_not_swipe" class to the element you want swipe to be disabled.

Taking your code as an example, you should have your html like this:

```
<ion-slides options="options">    
  <ion-slide-page>
  ... // A area content
  <ion-scroll class='do_not_swipe' direction="x" ...>
    <div style="width: 5000px; height: 100px" ...>
      // B area. Very wide content
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
  ... // C area content
 </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```